# How to sort javascript object keys in descending order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have JS object that looks like this:

```
data: {
 474481: {
    date: "02/14/2017",
    status_id: "474481"
​​ },
 497070: {
    date: "02/14/2017",
    status_id: "497070"
 },
 797070: {
    date: "02/14/2017",
    status_id: "497070"
 },
 597070: {
    date: "02/14/2017",
    status_id: "497070"
 }
}
```

How to sort data object by key in descending order? The final output should look like this:

```
data: {
     797070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     597070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     497070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     474481: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "474481"
    ​​ }
    }
```

I use JQuery 1.9 in my project. If anyone have suggestions how to sort the data please let me know.

Comment: Do you realise that sorting keys inside an object makes no sense? You can access object properties through keys, so why should keys have an order? Just see it as HashTables or Sets, the concept of order just makes no sense

Comment: You cannot "sort" the numeric properties of an object.

Comment: I'm not sure what is not making sense. I want the keys to be in descending instead of ascending order...

Comment: An object *barely* has object property order and even then it's not in all environments. Objects *traditionally* didn't have one because they were treated as hashes. Nowadays there is *some* order applied but only in some environments and even then you cannot change it for numeric keys.

Comment: It just makes no sense. What you see is just a visual output, since you used `console.log`. I could give some code that change the orders, but it's just aesthetics. If you are facing some problem, you should explain better what it is, and then we can help you

Comment: I want to display the records in the table. Records should be displayed in descending order. That's the only reason why I need that.

Comment: In that case, sort the *keys* and then iterate through them: `Object.keys(data).sort().forEach(key => { /* do whatever with data[key] here */ }`

Comment: So your problem is about putting properties in a table in a sorted manner, not about sorting the properties inside an object!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments, you can't sort an object in place, since object keys don't keep the order.

You can sort keys one moment before creating the *view*. Adding the rows in order, will create a sorted table:

```js
const data = {
     797070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     597070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     497070: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "497070"
     },
     474481: {
        date: "02/14/2017",
        status_id: "474481"
    
    }
};

const table = document.querySelector('table');
Object.keys(data)
.sort((a,b)=>b-a)
.forEach(key => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const id = document.createElement('td');
  const date = document.createElement('td');
  const status = document.createElement('td');
  id.innerText = key;
  date.innerText = data[key].date;
  status.innerText = data[key].status_id;
  tr.appendChild(id);
  tr.appendChild(date);
  tr.appendChild(status);
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>id</th><th>date</th><th>status</th></tr>
</table>
```